Complex Chain Rule (for differentiable functions in the real sense).
I've searched this site for hours for a solution to this and none of them have satisfied me or made any sense whatsoever! Here's the problem:
Suppose U and V are open sets in the complex plane. Prove that if $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to \mathbb{C}$ are two functions that are differentiable (in the real sense, that is, as functions of the two real variables x and y), and $h=g\circ f$, then
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z}$$
I've tried applying the formula for Wirtinger derivatives, but haven't got anywhere whatsoever. I've tried applying
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar f} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}$$
but that hasn't got me any further whatsoever. It's just left me confused about how dg/df becomes dg/dz, similar for the second term.
I've done research online to the solutions of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, which this exercise is from, and have found nothing which answers this question! It's hindering my self-study and I've been stuck on it for a few days now. Any help would be fantastic.

I dont get how you can go from dg/dz \circ f * df/dz to dg/dz * df/dz, and likewise for the z and fbars

That sort of notational shorthand of dropping the "$\circ f$" is standard convention that I bet you've used without batting an eye in real single-variable and multivariable calculus. In the single variable real case, the chain rule might be written as $\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dy}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$, without explicitly spelling out that the function for $y$ in terms of $x$ is implicitly being substituted into $\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dy}$.

Ah I see, I was pretty sure that it made sense to remove it, but was also incredibly worried about me being an idiot and looking for a simple solution if it wasn't there. Thanks!
